# Axios createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

New to react here. I'm getting this error: `xhr.js:177 POST https://localhost:44355/api/people/addperson 400` and I can't figure out why. I checked all over StackOverflow, but couldn't find a good answer from similar questions.

On my page, I have 3 textboxes (first name, last name, age) and an ADD button to add a person to a table beneath the textboxes. The error occurs when I click the add button.

Here's my controller:

```
public class PeopleController : ControllerBase
    {
        private string _connectionString;

        public PeopleController(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("ConStr");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("addperson")]
        public void AddPerson(Person person)
        {
            var repo = new PeopleRepository(_connectionString);
            repo.AddPerson(person);
        }
    }
```

Here's my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import AddEditPerson from './AddEditPerson';
import PersonRow from './PersonRow';
import axios from 'axios';
import { produce } from 'immer';

class PeopleTable extends React.Component {
    state = {
        people: [],
        person: {
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            age :''
        },
        isAdd : true
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        axios.get('/api/people/getpeople').then(response => {
            this.setState({ people: response.data })
        })
    }

    onAddClick = () => {
        axios.post('/api/people/addperson', this.state.person).then(() => {
            axios.get('/api/people/getpeople').then(response => {
                const person = {
                    firstName: '',
                    lastName: '',
                    age:''
                }
                this.setState({ people: response.data, person})
            })
        })
    }
}
//here I have a render function that shows a component with the textboxes 
//and the onClick for the add button is the onAddClick function above.
```

Comment: Since it's 400 this is a bad request.  Are you sure this is not a CORS problem ? Check your console maybe there is an error related to CORS. Or maybe your server expect to receive specific header ? And are you able to use the same API on Postman ?
(The good practice for POST request is to return the new added value, then you don't have to use a get request after each post)

Comment: You axios requests don't have a `.catch` block. You need to add one and print out the error to see what's happening - since it's a 400 there's likely an issue with the data you're sending, either missing values or the wrong shape or something

Comment: @Jayce444 I added a catch to log the error in the console, and here's what I got: `Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)`

Comment: @mamaj instead of logging the error, try to log the "response" property of it, e.g. `console.log(error.response)`. Also if you can edit backend code, you could add logging on the backend to try and see what the issue is

Comment: are you sure `https://localhost:44355` is not  you're front localhost port ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In newer versions of .Net they made a change to how the json gets parsed on the server.
It used to be that if you had a json like this: `{prop: "100"}`
and on the server you had a class like this:

```
public class Foo
{
   public int Prop {get; set;}
}
```

it would be able to convert the json to that C# object -
(notice that in the json prop is a string and in c# it’s an int).

In .Net Core 3.1 they changed this feature, and the json would no longer parse correctly.
Therefore, being that `this.state.person.age` is a string but in C# `Age` is an integer, it would be best to create a new object, parse the age, and send that in to the function.

I updated my code:

```
onAddClick = () => {
        const { firstName, lastName, age } = this.state.person;
        const person = { firstName, lastName, age: parseInt(age) }
        axios.post('/api/people/addperson', person).then(response => {
            const newState = produce(this.state, draft => {
                const person = {
                    firstName: '',
                    lastName: '',
                    age: ''
                }
                draft.person = person;
                draft.people.push(response.data);
            })

            this.setState(newState);            
        })
    }
```

With thanks to [@BFree](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15861/bfree)
and [@Zied Hf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5032071/zied-hf)
.